# Neo4j: Do queries on specific database?

Tags: database, neo4j

I´m new to Neo4j, and want to implement a service that makes use of it.

I´ve read the docs and searched for it, however I still didn´t get an answer to this simple question:

How do I **specify which database to query** in a Neo4j query?

E.g. I connected to bolt://localhost:7687, and have three databases in there: system, neo4j, and mydb. The *neo4j* database is the standard.

When I open the Neo4j browser and do a query such as `MATCH (n) RETURN n`, it automatically assumes that I want to query the standard DB which is called *neo4j*. However, I want to query another one, mydb.
My output when I query aforementioned query says

```
{
  "query": {
    "text": "match (n) return n",
    "parameters": {}
  },
  "queryType": "r",
  "counters": {
    "_stats": {
      "nodesCreated": 0,
      "nodesDeleted": 0,
      "relationshipsCreated": 0,
      "relationshipsDeleted": 0,
      "propertiesSet": 0,
      "labelsAdded": 0,
      "labelsRemoved": 0,
      "indexesAdded": 0,
      "indexesRemoved": 0,
      "constraintsAdded": 0,
      "constraintsRemoved": 0
    },
    "_systemUpdates": 0
  },
  "updateStatistics": {
    "_stats": {
      "nodesCreated": 0,
      "nodesDeleted": 0,
      "relationshipsCreated": 0,
      "relationshipsDeleted": 0,
      "propertiesSet": 0,
      "labelsAdded": 0,
      "labelsRemoved": 0,
      "indexesAdded": 0,
      "indexesRemoved": 0,
      "constraintsAdded": 0,
      "constraintsRemoved": 0
    },
    "_systemUpdates": 0
  },
  "plan": false,
  "profile": false,
  "notifications": [],
  "server": {
    "address": "localhost:7687",
    "version": "Neo4j/4.4.5",
    "agent": "Neo4j/4.4.5",
    "protocolVersion": 4.4
  },
  "resultConsumedAfter": {
    "low": 2,
    "high": 0
  },
  "resultAvailableAfter": {
    "low": 8,
    "high": 0
  },
  "database": {
    "name": "neo4j"
  }
}
```

In the last JSON value is the proof that the query was executed on database *neo4j*.

What do I have to add to my queries to instead query another database in the same DBMS?

Comment: EDIT: Based on the answers, to directly query a specific database, just write 'use mydb ...', so append the use-command as prefix to your Neo4j query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change/specify the database using the following options.

1. From the Neo4j Browser, you can select the database in the [sidebar](https://neo4j.com/docs/browser-manual/current/visual-tour/#sidebar).
2. In Cypher syntax, the [use](https://neo4j.com/developer/manage-multiple-databases/#operate-neo4j-db) command lets you choose different databases.
   `:use mydb`.
3. If you connect to Neo4j through an Application driver, you can specify the database while creating the session object.
   For example, if you are using the [Python driver](https://neo4j.com/docs/api/python-driver/current/api.html#database):

```
from neo4j import GraphDatabase
driver = GraphDatabase.driver(uri, auth=(user, password))
session = driver.session(database="mydb")
```

4. Specify the default database in a system-wide manner by modifying the [config_dbms.default_database](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/reference/configuration-settings/#config_dbms.default_database) value in the the [neo4j.conf file](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/neo4j-conf/#neo4j-conf).

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. While I don´t use Python, this code is pretty much language agnostic and translates well to other languages